# Resume a Java FTP file download

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I'm developing, in Java, an application that has to download from a server to client some very large files. So far I'm using the apache commons-net:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
client.retrieveFile(filename, out);
```

The connection commonly fails before the client finishes downloading the file. I need a way to resume the download of the file from the point where the connection failed, without downloading the whole file again, is it possible?

Comment: @LeeMeador Not true, many FTP servers support resuming from a specific byte offset.  I'd be surprised if commons-net does not support sending the starting offset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Things to know:

FileOutputStream has an append parameter, from doc;

> @param append if `true`, then bytes will be written
>                           to the end of the file rather than the beginning

FileClient has setRestartOffset which takes offset as parameter, from doc;

> @param offset  The offset into the remote file at which to start the
>                   next file transfer.  This must be a value greater than or
>                   equal to zero.

We need to combine these two;

```
boolean downloadFile(String remoteFilePath, String localFilePath) {
  try {
    File localFile = new File(localFilePath);
    if (localFile.exists()) {
      // If file exist set append=true, set ofset localFile size and resume
      OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(localFile, true);
      ftp.setRestartOffset(localFile.length());
      ftp.retrieveFile(remoteFilePath, fos);
    } else {
      // Create file with directories if necessary(safer) and start download
      localFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
      localFile.createNewFile();
      val fos = new FileOutputStream(localFile);
      ftp.retrieveFile(remoteFilePath, fos);
    }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Could not download file " + ex.getMessage());
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Commons-net `FTPClient` supports restarting transfers from a specific offset.  You'll have to keep track of what you've successfully retrieved, send the correct offset, and manage appending to the existing file.  Assuming, of course, that the FTP server you're connecting to supports the `REST` (restart) command.

Comment: can you please provide me one example? So far I'm looking into the FTP Client class, but there's so much stuff that I'm not quite sure what's best to use.